# How do I iterate over an audio file to not miss a part that fits a class?

Tags: python-3.x, audio, classification

I have an audio file that contains a part that matches an audio class I trained, for instance the letter R in a speech.

I would set an arbitrary length, like 20ms. Then I would split the audio file in 20ms intervals, send each to the predictclass.py and take the part where the probability for my class is the highest. Yet with this method I could be exactly at the corner of the wanted area, it could be stretched(longer than the original file) etc..

How do I cut an audio file to present the right portions to my classifier?

Comment: Dont know if I understood your problem correctly, but have you considered using overlapping windows?

Comment: @BGraf Please define overlapping windows in this context.

Comment: for example take the first 20ms from the start and the second window starting at 10ms until 30ms. in other words take 20ms windows which are only shifted by 10ms and thus overlap. this results in more datapoints to make predictions on and it is less likely to miss a characteristic point.

Comment: You should look at Dynamic Time Warping, check e.g. https://librosa.github.io/librosa/sequence.html#dynamic-time-warping and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach is to use overlap for your windows. Split the time-series into fixed-length analysis windows (ex window_length=10x20ms), but when computing the next window move it forward by a fraction of the window size. This size is usually called the 'hop length'. For example by 10% (hop_length=1x20ms). This means that the new window has 90% overlap with the previous.

[librosa.util.frame](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.util.frame.html) is a convenient function to do this on audio. It can also be done on spectrograms.